# OData version4 deep insert

Tags: odata

I am trying to find out how to deep insert in odata v4. Odata v4 specification says that deep insert is possible. But I have tried it in several ways but unable to find out the solution. Whenever I am trying to post an entity with its navigation data, it is being received null on server side. 
Anybody has any idea on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what service side do you use. However, Web API OData supports to post an entity with its navigation property.

For example, you have a Post method in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Customer customer)
{
  int key = _customers.Count();
  customer.Id = key + 1;
  _customers.Add(customer);
  return Created(customer);
}
```

You can issue a POST request on `http://..../odata/Customers` with the following sample request payload:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:33082
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 134

{
      "Id":9,
       "Name":"Customer #9",
       "Orders":[
        {
          "OrderId":2,"Price":3.3
        }
      ]
}
```

Thanks.